# What happens to gun mettle keys after the promotion ends?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The question is a two-parter.

**1) What happens to the keys in your inventory?**

The wiki states:

> During some special events, specialized keys are made available. These keys can be used with specifically associated series of crates, which regular keys cannot open. Remaining special keys, at the end of promotions, are transformed into regular keys.
>
> source: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Key

Is this true? Does this mean I have to buy new keys? This sounds a bit strange, especially if I still have some weapon cases remaining.

**2) What happens to keys in general (in the shop)?**

Will I still be able to buy keys from the store after the promotion ends?
If not and the above is true, that would render any remaining weapon cases i have left at the time useless.

I still see a lot of older keys in the store but not all of them and I can't find any info on what will happen with left-over weapon cases / keys after the promotion ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most crates are not tied to events.

The ones that are tend to be tied to various holidays, such as the Smissmas crates.

Smissmas keys are automatically converted to normal keys once Smissmas crates disappear (2013 and prior) or are no longer openable (Smissmas 2014).

All other crates and keys remain forever.  Case in point:  You can still buy keys from the Summer 2013 event in the Mann Co Store.

Comment: ok thanks, i figured but couldn't find it anywhere